# How can I create all vowel combinations of a String and add each combination to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, combinations

I'm having trouble printing off all vowel combinations of a given input.  My input is "SOMETHING" and I would like to print off all vowel combinations such as sxmxthxng where x is aeiou vowels.  I believe my problem is that I find a vowel, change it with all the others vowels and move on.  I need to continue down the rest of the word and find additional vowels and change those before proceeding.

Other refs

```
vowelList is an ArrayList containing all lower case vowels.
```

Code

```
 private static void createVowelCombos(String word) {
    Set<String> rmRepeats = new HashSet<>();
    StringBuilder sbAddWord = new StringBuilder(word);
    String[] splitWord = word.split("");

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
       // System.out.println("real word: " + splitWord[i]);

        if (splitWord[i].matches(".*[aeiou]")) {
           // System.out.println("Split: " + splitWord[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                sbAddWord.setCharAt(i, vowelList.get(j).charAt(0));
                System.out.println(sbAddWord.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Output with input "SOMETHING"

```
samething
semething
simething
something
sumething
sumathing
sumething
sumithing
sumothing
sumuthing
sumuthang
sumutheng
sumuthing
sumuthong
sumuthung
```

For some reason it is giving me all the combinations with 'u' but not the other vowels.  I would like to get all the results for the other vowels as well.

Comment: First, you should try to create a function that prints all permutations of a string.  So input abc will output abc, acb, bca, bac, cab, cba.  It's a pretty hard function to create if you've never made a recursive method before.

Comment: Yeah I have that -the problem with that is I don't want a list 12! long.  I'm trying to just build all vowel combinations.  Which I thought I could do with a nested loop.

Comment: Nested loops are useful when you know how many loops to nest. However, in this application, you have no idea how many vowels will be in the word. For this, you should use a recursive method.

Comment: Ok - any ideas on how to start it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as already suggested your problem can be best solved by using recursion (with backtracking). I've modified your code so as to print the required output. Have a look !!

```
private static void createVowelCombos(String word, int start) {
    StringBuilder sbAddWord = new StringBuilder(word);
    String[] splitWord = word.split("");
    if(start==splitWord.length)
    {
        System.out.println(word);
        return;
    }
    if (splitWord[start].matches(".*[aeiou]")) {
           // System.out.println("Split: " + splitWord[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                sbAddWord.setCharAt(start, vowelList.get(j).charAt(0));
                createVowelCombos(sbAddWord.toString(),start+1);
                //System.out.println(sbAddWord.toString());
            }
    }
    else
        createVowelCombos(sbAddWord.toString(),start+1);

}
```

Call createVowelCombos("something",0) from the calling method.